# SearchFilter misbehaves when data is a lot

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I tested the SearchFilter when I had around 10 records , and it was working fine, but I went ahead and tested it when the data records are above 200, it just returning the same data without searching or filtering the data , below is my View file :

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """Blog post lists"""
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=APPROVED)
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (PostsProtectOrReadOnly, IsMentorOnly)
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
    filter_fields = ('title', 'body', 'description',)
    search_fields = (
        '@title',
        '@body',
        '@description',
    )


    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get("order_by", None)
        author = self.request.GET.get("author", None)
        if ordering == 'blog_views':
            queryset = queryset.annotate(
                address_views_count=Count('address_views')).order_by(
                '-address_views_count')

        if author:
            queryset = queryset.filter(owner__email=author)

        return queryset
```

This is how I search :

```
/api/v1/blogs/?search=an+elephant
```

But it just returns back all the data instead of filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you made an override of the `filter_queryset`, it will no longer work with the `filter_backends` to filter the data. You should filter the queryset further, by making a super call:

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    # …
    
    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        ordering = self.request.GET.get('order_by', None)
        author = self.request.GET.get('author', None)
        # filter queryset with filter_backends 🖟
        queryset = super().filter_queryset(queryset)
        if ordering == 'blog_views':
            queryset = queryset.annotate(
                address_views_count=Count('address_views')
            ).order_by('-address_views_count')
        
        if author:
            queryset = queryset.filter(owner__email=author)
        
        return queryset
```

Comment: Hi Willem, there's another weird issue, I know this could be another question, so  the issue is why is it that when I use one word the search returns back the data, but when I use 2 words or more , it brings back empty list . e,g If I use some thing like this doens't work :
`/api/v1/blogs/?search=an+elephant` but if I use something like this it works :
`/api/v1/blogs/?search=elephant` what causes this ?